# Global message for different message boxes

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following **simplified** VBA code which shows a message box once the user clicks on a button in the Excel spreadsheet:

Message Box A:

```
Sub Message_Box_A ()
Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo)
If Answer = vbYes Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 1
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Message Box B:

```
Sub Message_Box_B ()
Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo)
If Answer = vbYes Then
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = 1
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Is there a way how I can "globalize" the text of the message box *"Do you want to continue?"* so if I want to change it I do not have to go through each VBA code of each message box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a function like this:

```
Function Answer() As Long
 Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo)
End Function
```

then you can use it like this:

```
Sub Message_Box_A ()

If Answer = vbYes Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 1
Else
End If
End Sub
```

**Edit**:

If we want autocomplete works like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1770293/4039286) as @Peh comment. we can use:

```
    Function Answer() As VbMsgBoxResult
     Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo)
    End Function
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Function Answer() As VbMsgBoxResult`?

Comment: Thank you @Peh., [MsgBox Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx) returns an Integer and Long is better than Integer.

Comment: Non the less it should be VbMsgBoxResult so autocomplete works

Comment: @Peh, please add watch to the variable to see that its type is Long.

Comment: @Peh, I thought you are talking about data type, yes you are right if we want autocomplete works like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1770293/4039286), I will edit my answer, Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a constant. In a module insert …

```
Const msgContinue = "Do you want to continue?"

Sub Message_Box_A ()
    Answer = MsgBox(msgContinue, vbYesNo)
    If Answer = vbYes Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 1
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Terse version:

```
Public Function PlsContinue() As Boolean
    PlsContinue = MsgBox("Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo) = vbYes
End Function

Sub Message_Box_A()
    If PlsContinue Then Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = 1
End Sub

Sub Message_Box_B()
    If PlsContinue Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = 1
End Sub
```

Edited to add - flexible version, use as many buttons as you like and feed in different values from each:

```
Public Function PlsContinue() As Boolean
    PlsContinue = MsgBox("Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo) = vbYes
End Function

Sub Message_Box(ByVal sht As String, ByVal cel As String, vlu As Long)
    If PlsContinue Then Sheets(sht).Range(cel).Value = vlu
End Sub

Sub Message_Box_A()
    Message_Box "Sheet1", "A1", 1
End Sub

Sub Message_Box_B()
    Message_Box "Sheet2", "A1", 1
End Sub

Sub Message_Box_C()
    Message_Box "Sheet1", "A2", 2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, but maybe following code might help you (in particular if you have too many `Message_Box_X ()` Subs).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    WhichButton = "Sheet1"
    Message_Box (WhichButton)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    WhichButton = "Sheet2"
    Message_Box (WhichButton)
End Sub



Sub Message_Box(WB As String)
    msgContinue = "Do you want to continue?"
    Answer = MsgBox(msgContinue, vbYesNo)
    If Answer = vbYes Then
        Sheets(WB).Range("A1").Value = 1
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```